# Ember- return the response from a nested promise in a closure action

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Using the pattern below I can return the result of a save operation in my route to a component, using closure actions. This works fine.

**Route**

```js
actions: {
    submit: function(values) {
      var user = this.store.createRecord('user', values);
      return user.save();
    },
  }
```

**Component**

```js
this.attrs.submit(values).then((response) => {
  //Handle success
}).catch(error => {
  //Handle error
});
```

In my **submit** action, I would like to first fetch the license object that the user belongs to and then set that on the user object before saving, as below.

The problem is that `return user.save();` is now in the callback for query operation, and is not being returned from the submit action.

How can I restructure my code so that I can query the license record, and then return the result of `user.save()` to my component?

```js
submit: function(values) {
  var user = this.store.createRecord('user', values);
  this.get('store').query('license', {
    filter: {
      code: values.licenseCode
    }
  }).then(function(licenses) {
    var license = licenses.get("firstObject");
    user.set('license', license);
    return user.save();
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No restructuring necessary. The [`then` method already does this magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) of getting you the result from the callback. You just need to return the promise it gives you:

```
submit: function(values) {
  var user = this.store.createRecord('user', values);
  return this.get('store').query('license', {
//^^^^^^
    filter: {
      code: values.licenseCode
    }
  }).then(function(licenses) {
//  ^^^^^
    var license = licenses.get("firstObject");
    user.set('license', license);
    return user.save();
//  ^^^^^^
  });
},
```